# Was ist das entsprechende Wort für „Interviewee“?

Tags: single-word-request

**Kontext:**

Es geht hier um eine Anhörung wie die Anhörungen beim Gericht oder bei der Polizei (aber halt inoffiziell). Die Anhörung wurde 5 Minuten vor dem Termin von dem *Interviewee* abgesagt.

Was ist das passende Wort hier für *Interviewee*?

Wie kann man z.B sagen:

> Der Termin ist nicht stattgefunden, denn der *Interviewee* hat 5 Minuten vor dem Termin abgesagt.

Comment: Und was sagt Dein bevorzugtes Wörterbuch? Hast Du eigene Ideen und Vorschläge?

Comment: @Stephie Befragter

Answer (score 6):

Wie auch beim Trainee gibt es wohl kein hübsches, universelles deutsches Pendant. Daher kommt es auf den Zusammenhang an, ob es ein **Interviewpartner** (auf Augenhöhe) ist oder ein **Interviewgast** (im Studio), oder ob es vielleicht auch nur ein **Befragter** ist (auf der Straße, bei einer Befragung). Im hippen, jungen Umfeld wird vlt. sogar **Interviewee** verstanden. Ansonsten spricht man im Deutschen auch durchaus vom **Interviewten** (oder von »die Interviewte«).

Konkret geht es bei Gericht bzw. der Polizei eher hölzern bzw. deutsch zu, entsprechend etwa:

> Der Termin hat nicht stattgefunden, denn der Befragte hat 5 Minuten vor dem Termin abgesagt.

Eigentlich müsste es auch »die zu befragende Person« heißen, da das „Interview“ noch gar nicht stattgefunden hat. Bei Gericht/Polizei spricht man wahrscheinlich eher von »als Zeuge geladen« denn vom »Interviewten«, oder?

Comment: Hier geht es nicht um Bezeugung. Es geht um ein Interview bzw. eine Anhörung.

Comment: Was denn nun? Interview oder Anhörung? Das sind zwei verschiedene Dinge. Meinst du ein Interview der Presse oder eine Anhörung vor Gericht oder Staatsanwaltschaft? Letzteres: der Angehörte oder der Befragte. Ersteres: der Interviewte.

Comment: Kein Zeuge, sondern ein Sachverständiger dann? Der Beschwerdeführer? Der Beschuldigte? Der Kläger? Jedenfalls gibt es, je nach Situation, diverse Begriffe.

Comment: Man kann von der Polizei interviewt werden und eine TV-Befragung kann zur Anhörung ausarten. Für die Sache liegen »zwischen-sehen« und »an-hören« dabei nicht sooo weit auseinander. Allerdings ist eine „polizeiliche Anhörung“ sicher kein „Spaß-Interview“.

Comment: Das englische *interview* ist weiter gefasst als das deutsche *Interview*, wobei letzteres dabei ist, von ersterem Bedeutungen zu übernehmen.

Comment: @CarstenS: Stimmt! D. h. leider auch, dass “interviewee” weiter gefasst ist: Interviewter, Unterredeter, Gesprächspartner, Befragter. Eine Übersetzung ist also (leider) stark vom Kontext abhängig.